# UDP sending packet fail in C# mono Linux

Tags: c#, sockets, mono, udp

I have written 2 UDP client / server application in visual studio C#. As I run these 2 application in windows everything goes OK, and transmission of packets are done correctly. I port these projects on Linux and compile them by MonoDevelope , when Run these applications, no UDP packets pass through my network interface card. As well tcpdump dose not capture any UDP packets. Doses Mono has a malfunction on transmission of UDP packets?
Regards.

Comment: I am guessing but it probably can help. Are the ports open? Does the string output the same new line character as on Windows? Try to send the packets via some utility so you can see whether the problem is in the program or in environment.

Comment: Thank to Keiv.fly, The ports was blocked in my system firewall. Mono C# is Ok by transmission of UDP packets.

Comment: shows us de code amigo

Answer (score 0):

The port is blocked by the firewall in Linux.